# What's the difference between a single-contact alveolar trill and alveolar flap/tap

Tags: phonetics, trills, rhotics

is there any difference between the two? is it even possible to produce an alveolar trill with a single vibration of the tongue?

Comment: No difference, except that if there's only one contact it's not a trill, just a tap.

Comment: It’s not possible to produce a trill with just one vibration/contact, because _that is a tap_. The definition of a trill is multiple taps in rapid succession; if there’s only one, it fails the definition.

Comment: What you're asking is like asking about a difference between a one-storeyed cottage and a one-storeyed skyscraper. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest consulting Ladefoged & Maddieson *The sounds of the world's languages*, p. 217 ff for the distinction. They state that

> The primary characteristic of a trill is that it is the vibration of
> one speech organ against another, driven by the aerodynamic
> conditions. One of the soft moveable parts of the vocal tract is
> placed close enough to another surface, so that when a current of air
> of the right strength passes through the aperture created by this
> configuration, a repeating pattern of closing and opening of the flow
> channel occurs

...

> a sufficiently narrow aperture must be created and an adequate airflow
> through the aperture must occur. The aperture size and airflow must
> fall within critical limits for trilling to occur, and quite small
> deviations mean that it will fail

Therefore, they note that

> trills tend to vary with non-trilled pronunciations. So with trills,
> as with voicing, there is a potential conflict between an acoustic
> definition (more than one period of actual vibration) and an
> articulatory definition (positioning of the articulators in a
> configuration such that, given the right aerodynamic conditions,
> vibration would occur).

They then resolve this conflict, saying that

> we will consider trills to be sounds made with an articulatory
> configuration appropriate for vibration, regardless of whether
> vibration actually occurs.

Accordingly, a single-trill trill is not the same as a flap/tap, but only if you accept their *articulatory* definition of a trill. As for flaps and taps,

> a flap is a sound in which a brief contact between the articulators is
> made by moving the active articulator tangentially to the site of the
> contact, so that it strikes the upper surface of the vocal tract in
> passing; a tap is a sound in which a brief contact between the
> articulators is made by moving the active articulator directly towards
> the roof of the mouth.

So it depends on how you define tap, flap and trill.

Catford, in *A Practical Introduction to Phonetics*, does not "define" trills, but his description of them (p. 66) is based on articulation, not acoustic result – I would say that there is no disagreement between Catford and Ladefoged & Maddieson on what a trill is.